# microposts are not showing up in a ol (ordered list)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I have been working with Michael Hartl's tutorial and I am almost finished.  However, I got near the end and am have a problem styling the micropost section of the "user/show/" page. I would like all the microposts to be under one another. Currently they are showing like this:

[image: unordered list]

custom.css.scss

```
.microposts {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  }
  .user {
    margin-top: 5em;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .content {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 60px;
    img {
      display: block;
      padding: 5px 0;
    }
  }
  .timestamp {
    color: $gray-light;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 60px;
  }
  .gravatar {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}

aside {
  textarea {
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}

span.picture {
  margin-top: 10px;
  input {
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

microposts.html.erb

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user), micropost.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %></span>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
</li>
```

show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

If someone could please help me, it would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the floats. Try adding `clear: both;` to your `.microposts .li` SASS

```
.microposts {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    clear: both;
  }
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ha28wfev/1/)